# Powershell Get-Date in 24 hour time

Tags: powershell, datetime, format

I'm trying to format Get-Date in powershell.  I'm using this,

Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"

and it is returning the correct date and time except it is not using 24 hour time so this format, 20201109033010, is returned for both 3:30 AM and 3:30 PM.  I would like it to show 20201109153010 for 3:30 PM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct date formatting to get hours in 24 hour format is HH not hh. This should work for you:

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!